# What kind of pooling with non ReLU non-linearities?

Tags: pooling, conv-neural-network

in a Convolutional Neural Network it is customary to have a ReLU, then max pooling. If we would have a symmetric non-linearity, e.g. $max(w_1 x, w_2x)$, would it make sense to have a max absolute pooling instead of max pooling layer?

Comment: What is meant by "max(w_1 x, w_2x)"?

Comment: A hypothetical non-linear function (in fact, a tanh could also work for this example, as it also return negative activations). For such a function you could also get negative values. With pooling would we still want to take the max, or the absolute max. In the latter case you encourage the strongest activations, be it positive or negative to survive.

In other words, with tanh does max pooling make sense?

Comment: I see what you are saying. I have heard of both being done. However I found much better results just sticking with regular max pooling. It may depend on the training data and network architecture though.